# Simulating the impact of wind on an electronically controlled turbine

Tags: simulation

I'm looking for a software that can simulate the impact of wind and a program algorithm on wind turbine.

The program algorithm rotates the turbine around its central column based on the wind direction that is provided by a separate sensor. The sensor that provide the wind direction is not included in the simulation.

I was wondering if I could use Octave since it has a programming aspect  that allows to implement the rotation algorithm. I'm not sure if Octave can provide simulation of the impact of the wind on the model though.

I prefer a Linux software. Also, I prefer that the simulation shows the stress points on the model in case of a strong wind like in the ocean.

Comment: Are you looking for a Visual simulation or a numeric one?

Comment: A visual simulation.

Comment: Not sure how accurate it is, but you could use Blender (www.Blender.org) to do the simulation. But you would need to model it first, and port the algorithm to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a visual simulation then you could use the [Blender 3D](https://www.blender.org/) Game/Physics Engine but to get the numbers, *especially for stress points*, to put into it you will probably need to do some Finite Element Analysis with [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org)/[SfePy](http://sfepy.org/doc-devel/index.html)/[FEniCS](http://fenicsproject.org/about/components.html#about-components-dolfin).